# Bluetooth Scanner sets system-wide keyboard, UITextFields wont show soft keyboard on responder

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

This is a bit curly, and I am not sure there is an answer.

I have a simple application that uses a handheld bluetooth scanner paired to an iPhone to keep lists of parcels coming of the back of trucks.

The scanner acts-as a keyboard sending character strings on scan.  In the application the user must pair with the scanner in settings.

Upon scan complete a textfield is populated with the sent string.  The last character is a return char, at which time the contents are added to a datasource for a UITableView.

The problem is this;  Once the scanner has been used once the system *seems* to recognize it as the only user input.  Any future attempt to bring up the soft keyboard fails.  This goes beyond the scanning application ~ quitting the app completely and attempting to use Apples SMS app also fails to bring up the keyboard.

Is there *any* (apple legal) way of either using both or setting preferred input device?  There seems to be a myriad of legal issues around Bluetooth and accessories, I am wondering if I am out of luck.  Has anyone heard of anything that might help me out?

It appears I am not alone [(as in this post regarding iPad soft keyboard)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326189/show-iphone-soft-keyboard-even-thought-a-hardware-keyboard-is-connected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've pretty much covered it.

According to [HT4111](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4111):

> You can stop using a Bluetooth accessory by either turning off the accessory, or turning off Bluetooth on iPad.

According to Gizmodo's [10 iPad Essential Tips & Tricks](http://gizmodo.com/5508399/10-essential-ipad-tips--tricks):

> When you have a Bluetooth keyboard connected to your iPad, the virtual keyboard will cease to appear. (This is a good thing.) However, what if, for some random reason, you needed that virtual keyboard? Don't unpair your Bluetooth. Just... Hit the eject key on Apple's physical keyboard. It'll bring up the virtual one.

If there's an off button on the scanner, then hit that. If you have an actual bluetooth keyboard, then use that (or hit its eject button if it's an Apple keyboard). If you have control over the design of the scanner hardware, then you can add a "show keyboard" button (I'm not sure which keycode Apple uses for "eject") if turning it off is too tedious.

Comment: Thanks for your time and response tc, the problem is that turning off the scanner requires you to exit the application and go into settings to re-pair it.  Less than ideal!  The eject button on Apple Bluetooth keyboard isn't an option and we don't have control over the hardware; these are commercially available handheld scanners. 

I think the iPhone/iPad is intelligently dealing with what it sees as a valid keyboard input device and what I am trying to do isn't intended behaviour according to Apple's prescription.

Oh well, back to the drawing board :)

Comment: If you need to re-pair, then the scanner definitely isn't behaving as it should — pariring should survive a power cycle.

Comment: did you ever have luck with this?  is there a way to list the device and just disconnect that device and not actually turn off the bluetooth?

Answer (score 0):

Socket Mobile just added a new "double tap" feature to their Bluetooth barcode scanner that lets you open the onscreen keboard. There's a video demo on YouTube. http://www.youtube.com/socketmobile