# iPad sees bluetooth device and won't show onscreen keyboard?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, iphone-sdk-3.0

When my iPad is connected to my bluetooth scanner it won't show the keyboard in my app.

Anyone know of a work around for something like this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489548/bluetooth-scanner-sets-system-wide-keyboard-uitextfields-wont-show-soft-keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slee, which bluetooth scanner are you using? If it's the Socket CHS, they just came out with a firmware upgrade that lets you push a button to open the onscreen keyboard. There's a demo on YouTube: http://www.youtube.com/socketmobile