# Using Static Library in Xcode 4.6.x i.e. Koamtac iOS SDK Integration

Tags: ios, static-libraries, barcode, kdc

Here's a link to the Koamtac iOS SDK that i'm trying to use: [Koamtac iOS SDK](http://www.koamtac.com/downloads/iOS.SDK.V2.03.04.zip). It includes a static library along with some sample code.

**Background**

I'm working on an iPhone application that requires a batch barcode import functionality, using [KDC scanner device](http://www.koamtac.com/techDownloads.html). The iPhone application is ARC based, and is built using Standard (armv7, armv7s) architecture.

**Problem**

I was able to run the KTDemo application (provided with the SDK). However, I'm having a difficult time setting-up the SDK in my own application -- so that I can use iKEA library (libiKEA.a) via KScan wrapper class (written by Koamtac). The steps mentioned in their programming guide look obsolete.

Can anyone help me setup the SDK in my project? -- That is, add the static library (libiKEA.a) along with the wrapper classes inside my iOS application project.

**More Specific Problem Description**

If I try to add a static library in my project, I get the following warning:

> ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/gm/Desktop/KDC
>   SDK/Lib/Debug-iphonesimulator/libiKEA.a, file was built for archive
>   which is not the architecture being linked (armv7):
>   /Users/gm/Desktop/KDC SDK/Lib/Debug-iphonesimulator/libiKEA.a

However, the KTDemo source-code doesn't have that issue. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you open the folder that contains the iKEA library, then look in the parent folder you'll see different options for Simulator and Device. Add the library for the device and it will work.