# How can I switch on Bluetooth on the iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios

I'd like to know, how I can activate Bluetooth on the iOS Simulator. I use XCODE 7.2.1 on a MacBook pro. If I enter the settings, I have no Bluetooth option to set. Could somebody help me ?

Answer (score 14):

You can't activate it because it doesn't exist.  They dropped support a few years ago because of all the issues they had with it.  You have to use a real device unfortunately.
This was confirmed by an Apple staff member as recently as a few months ago: 
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/14983

Comment: Is this still the case?