# Nativescript ios: open vitrual keyboard when connected to bluetooth scanner

Tags: ios, nativescript, keyboard-events

I have a bluetooth scanner connected to iPad.
ios doesn't support bluetooth spp mode, so I have to set scanner into HID. 
However, after that, the virtual keyboard disappear. 
I tried [ios keyboard] plugin.[1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager) No luck. 
I assume this may be a common case if your app work with bluetooth device(keyboard).

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: that plugin is just to push up the screen in case an input gets a focus and keyboard pops out.

Comment: you can use this plugin https://www.nsplugins.com/plugin/nativescript-keyboardshowing and see what all events are firing

Comment: Hi Nathan,  keyboard statues is open when the textfield is focused. However, since it is connected to bluetooth keyboard,  still cannot see virtual keyboard.

Comment: Looks like its a problem with iOS itself, refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290417/force-on-screen-keyboard-to-show-when-bluetooth-keyboard-connected for more info.

Comment: @Ash you can try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326189/show-iphone-soft-keyboard-even-though-a-hardware-keyboard-is-connected/3837131#3837131

Comment: @Manoj Thanks for your reply. I have no ios native code bg. I did find that solution but it maybe not suitable for my case

Comment: @NarendraMongiya Hi~ yes, I think I can work from hardware side