# Keyboard behavior when forced open with inputAccessoryView?

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad, keyboard, ios5

I have a device connected to my iPad that is acting as an external keyboard, however, I still need a soft keyboard in my program.  I have had some luck using the following article: [Show iphone soft keyboard even thought a hardware keyboard is connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326189/show-iphone-soft-keyboard-even-thought-a-hardware-keyboard-is-connected), but iOS 5 has broken this method.  The bottom of the soft keyboard is slightly cut off in most views, but others only half the keyboard appears inside the window and not where you would expect it to.

All of the following code works in my AppDelegate.m file in iOS4, but not in iOS5.

forceKeyboard is called after UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification is sent.

```
-(void) textFieldBegan: (NSNotification *) theNotification
{
    UITextField *theTextField = [theNotification object];
    theTextField.inputAccessoryView = inputAccessoryView;
    [self performSelector:@selector(forceKeyboard) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
}


//Change the inputAccessoryView frame
-(void) forceKeyboard
{
    inputAccessoryView.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 502, 1024, 265);

    int movementDistance = 1;
    float movementDuration = 0.3f;

    [UIView beginAnimations: @"kb_anim_open" context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];
    inputAccessoryView.superview.frame = CGRectOffset(inputAccessoryView.superview.frame, 0, movementDistance);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Close Keyboard is called after UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification is sent.

```
-(void) textFieldEnd: (NSNotification *) theNotification
{
    UITextView *theTextView = [theNotification object];
    [theTextView resignFirstResponder];
    [self performSelector:@selector(forceCloseKeyboard) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
}


-(void) forceCloseKeyboard
{
    inputAccessoryView.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 502, 1024, 265);

    int movementDistance = 502;
    float movementDuration = 0.3f;

    [UIView beginAnimations: @"kb_anim_close" context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];
    inputAccessoryView.superview.frame = CGRectOffset(inputAccessoryView.superview.frame, 0, movementDistance);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Any ideas on how I can tame a soft keyboard would be greatly appreciated; I've tried wrestling with the superview.frame values for awhile but with no luck.

Thanks for reading.

---

**UPDATE**

I have figured out a setup that opens and closes the keyboard in iOS 4 and 5, but does not animate.  Again, this is all in the AppDelegate where "textFieldBegan" and "textFieldEnd" are called by notifications sent when a user begins and ends editing respectively.

```
-(void) textFieldBegan: (NSNotification *) theNotification
{
    UITextField *theTextField = [theNotification object];

     if (!inputAccessoryView) {
         inputAccessoryView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 1)];
     }else{
         inputAccessoryView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 1);
     }

     theTextField.inputAccessoryView = inputAccessoryView;

     [self performSelector:@selector(forceKeyboard) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
}

-(void) textFieldEnd: (NSNotification *) theNotification
{
    NSString *classstr = NSStringFromClass([[theNotification object] class]);

    UITextView *theTextView = [theNotification object];
    [self performSelector:@selector(forceCloseKeyboard) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
    [theTextView resignFirstResponder];
}


//Change the inputAccessoryView frame
-(void) forceKeyboard
{
    //default center = 512, 591
    inputAccessoryView.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 415, 1024, 353);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations: ^ { [inputAccessoryView.superview transform]; }];
}
-(void) forceCloseKeyboard  //Unnecessary?
{
    inputAccessoryView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 0);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations: ^ { [inputAccessoryView transform]; }];
}
```

It looks as if the "forceCloseKeyboard" method isn't really doing anything as it looks like when the textField resigns responder it closes the keyboard anyway.  I leave it here in case someone can come up with a way to animate the keyboard opening and closing.