# HTML5 iOS/Android Keyboard Button

Tags: android, ios, keyboard

Is there any method you can call in HTML5/javaScript that will force the on-screen keyboard to appear in iOS/Android?

I am not looking for an HTML5 keyboard, but simply to notify the device that it needs to display the internal on-screen keyboard.

Thanks

Comment: What is the keyboard for? iOS will automatically show the keyboard if a text field has the focus, and hide it otherwise.

Comment: In this case, the user has connected a Bluetooth barcode scanner, which iOS recognizes as a keyboard, and thus, minimizes the on-screen keyboard by default.

Comment: Here's the iOS Solution: [Show iphone soft keyboard even though a hardware keyboard is connected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326189/show-iphone-soft-keyboard-even-thought-a-hardware-keyboard-is-connected/3837131#3837131)

Comment: Marcus, thanks for the link.  Looks like exactly what I was searching for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Android you can use this:

```
 public void showSoftKeyboard(View v) {
        Activity activity = (Activity) v.getContext();
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)  activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
```

OR just call:

```
((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

For iOS I found this one:

```
$('#element').focus().blur().focus();
```

Comment: I have doubt about the ios one, are you sure , Is this working ?