# Keyboard not appearing when connecting smart card reader to iPhones with type-c port. i.e. iPhone 15/ 15 pro

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard, smartcard-reader

**Description:**
I'm facing an issue where the keyboard does not appear on my iPhone 15/15 Pro when I connect a smart card reader via Type-C. This issue occurs across all applications and is not specific to any particular app.

**Additional Information:**
This issue occurs consistently across different applications, indicating that it's not app-specific.
I have tried restarting the device and re-connecting the smart card reader, but the issue persists.
The smart card reader is recognized by the iPhone, as I can interact with it using compatible apps.

**Device and Software Information:**
•⁠  ⁠iPhone 15/15 Pro
•⁠  ⁠iOS version: 17.3.1

**Query:**
Has anyone else encountered a similar issue with connecting a smart card reader to the iPhone 15/15 Pro? Are there any known workarounds or solutions to resolve this issue? Any insights or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

**Steps to Reproduce:**
•⁠  ⁠Connect a smart card reader to the iPhone 15/15 Pro via Type-C port.
•⁠  ⁠Open any application with a text field (e.g., Notes, Messages, Safari).
•⁠  ⁠Tap on the text field to start typing.

**Expected Behavior:**
Upon tapping the text field, the keyboard should appear, allowing the user to input text.

**Actual Behavior:**
The keyboard does not appear when tapping on the text field, making it impossible to input text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the smart card reader presents a "keyboard" HID profile via USB then iOS will suppress the on screen keyboard as it believes that a hardware keyboard is connected.

If the keyboard has a button that maps to the "eject" key scan code, that will trigger iOS to display the on-screen keyboard.

If your device cannot send this scan code, then there are some other suggestions in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326189/show-iphone-soft-keyboard-even-though-a-hardware-keyboard-is-connected) but they are very old,  so they may not still work.

The best solution is to reconfigure the device, if possible, so that it does not present a keyboard profile.

[this thread](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/usb-c-yubikey-issues-with-iphone-15.2403967/) indicates that it is a known problem with the Yubikey.

> “Currently, the keyboard not showing when the YubiKey is inserted in the USB-C port is an expected behavior due to the OTP application behaving similarly to USB keyboards. Meaning, the Yubico OTP uses HID protocol (same as a USB keyboard) to enter the OTP codes.

You can use Yubikey manager to disable the OTP feature which will restore keyboard functionality but it prevents OTP entry from the Yubikey.

Comment: Thank you for your input. The smartcard I am using i.e. YubiKey, is primarily used for certificate and key storage and doesn't have keyboard functionality. In this case, the issue with the keyboard not appearing on iPhone 15/15 Pro when the smart card reader is connected seems unrelated to the keyboard profile of the device.

Given that the smart card reader doesn't present a keyboard HID profile, the suppression of the on-screen keyboard by iOS appears to be unintentional. It's possible that there might be a compatibility issue or a bug causing this behavior. 
Any more idea of the cause?

Comment: See my update; the OTP functionality of the Yubikey results in the Yubikey presenting as a keyboard